# SQL Query to get all records from one table and join on another including any additional unique records

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

I need to get every unique batch number from two tables including a product code, date received, expiry date, and quantity.

I have a table of **unique batches requiring dates** (bmwohm) and a table of  **batches with dates (some duplicated)** (stquem).

I can select the unique batch numbers (works_order) from bmwohm which will return the correct data but for the second table I need to find the first matching batch number with associated fields (as some are duplicated) including all batches that weren't included in the first query.

This is the query I have for the bmwohm table:

```
select works_order, product_code, quantity_required
from bmwohm
where warehouse = 'W1' or warehouse = 'W3'
```

This is the incorrect distinct query I have for the stquem table:

```
select distinct on(batch_number), prod_code, date_received, expiry_date, quantity
from stquem
where warehouse = 'W1' or warehouse = 'W3'
```

**How would I return distinct batches and the fields associated with that record?**

I've attempted to combine the two via a right join returning both quantity fields and product codes using:

```
select works_order, product_code, quantity_required, batch_number, prod_code,
        date_received, expiry_date, quantity
from bmwohm as uniqueLots
right join scheme.stquem as duplicateLots
on uniqueLots.works_order = (select distinct duplicateLots.batch_number) 
where (uniqueLots.warehouse = 'W1' or uniqueLots.warehouse = 'W3')
and (duplicateLots.warehouse = 'W1' or duplicateLots.warehouse = 'W3')
```

**How can I combine the two to give a result of unique batches with an additional four fields?**

Answer (score 0):

Try modifyig your query a bit like

```
select distinct b.works_order, 
                b.product_code, 
                b.quantity_required, 
                s.batch_number, 
                s.prod_code,
                s.date_received, 
                s.expiry_date, 
                s.quantity
from bmwohm b
join scheme.stquem s
on b.works_order = s.batch_number 
where b.warehouse in ('W1','W3')
and s.warehouse in ('W1' , 'W3');
```

Comment: I think this would work with a left join to contain all batch numbers as there could be some that are not in stquem. This would then have to be combined in some way with the distinct batches from the stquem table that are not in the first selection. How would I go about returning associated fields with a distinct item?

Comment: @matt, not sure if I really understood what you are saying.

Comment: theres two tables with two lists of batches. all unique batches need to be selected from both lists. if a batch exits in both tables get the associated date fields. Does that make sense? So I'd need two selects, one that left joins onto stquem and the other that selects only the distinct batch records but brings back the associated fields. This is the real question of how to get multiple fields using distinct as there seems to be no way of applying distinct to one field (batch number) and then bringing back the other fields. How can this be done?